# How to increment a time meter on a game?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to increment the time meter on the game but it is not ticking and I am not sure why. What am I doing wrong?

```js
//Time that increments in the game
    var timeId = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    var time = 0
    function updateTime(){
        time++;
        $(‘#timer’).text(time);
    }

    //Start the timer
    function startTime() {
      
    }
```

```html
    <div id="timer">
            Game Time: 0
          </div>
```

Comment: `$(‘#timer’)` has weird quote characters.. change them to regular single quotes: http://jsfiddle.net/enchjpgw/

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to the "fancy" apostrophes. Here's a working example that fixes that.

Note that this example also includes the text "Game Time:" as part of the content being written to the `div`. Before that, it was just showing the number itself.

```js
//Time that increments in the game
var timeId = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
var time = 0;
function updateTime(){
    time++;
    $('#timer').text('Game Time: ' + time);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">Game Time: 0</div>
```